# Probability density function of the angle between two random points on a sphere

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, trigonometry, probability-distributions

Suppose we have a sphere and we sample two points uniformly and independently on the sphere, noted A and B. The sphere is centered in O. I want to calculate the probability density function of the angle AOB (in rad).

Comment: Hint: WLOG the first point is a pole. Then the density function is directly proportional to the area of an infinitesimal conic stripe determine by the center angle $\theta$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, why is it determined by the conic stripe? I do not get it

Comment: In fact a spherical segment, but for computation you consider a conic approximation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, you said the density function is directly proportional to the area of segment, does this means the area of the segment should be divided by the surface area of the sphere(4$\pi$)?

Comment: Of course, the density must be normalized.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ independent and uniformly random on the  unit sphere $S_n$, then by symmetry, $X\cdot Y$ and $X_1$  have exactly thesame distribution. This can be computed exactly using special functions, but if you're in high dimensions (i.e large $n$), then the distribution of $X_1$ (and therefore, of $X\cdot Y$) will be $N(0, 1/n)$, roughly.